# The argument type 'ImageProvider<Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'

Tags: flutter, image, pdf

I'm trying to display an Image in a PDF, using the Flutter pdf package.

```
pw.Image( myImage ),
```

This line is giving me the error

> The argument type 'ImageProvider<Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'

I tried adding a typecast

```
pw.Image( myImage as ImageProvider),
```

But then I just get an "unnecessary cast error", in addition to the other error.

This is the line where I'm defining `myImage` :

```
var myImage = FileImage( File('path-to-the-image/image.png') );
```

Is there a difference between `ImageProvider\<Object\>` and `ImageProvider` ?

How do I make the type cast / tranlation ?

Answer (score 0):

The `Image` constructor from `pdf` package is expecting a parameter of type [`ImageProvider`](https://pub.dev/documentation/pdf/latest/widgets/ImageProvider-class.html) that also comes from the same package. You are providing an [`ImageProvider`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageProvider-class.html) from the Flutter framework, which is why the error shown.

Use one of the classes that extends `ImageProvider` from pdf package to create an `ImageProvider` that can be passed to the `pw.Image` constructor. [`MemoryImage`](https://pub.dev/documentation/pdf/latest/widgets/MemoryImage-class.html)  and [`RawImage`](https://pub.dev/documentation/pdf/latest/widgets/RawImage-class.html) allows you to create an `ImageProvider` from a `Uint8List`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Read this documentation for more example: https://pub.dev/packages/pdf#examples

in your case, you need to use `MemoryImage`

```
final  myImage = pw.MemoryImage(File('path-to-the-image/image.png').readAsBytesSync());
```

now you can use it as

```
pw.Center( child: pw.Image(image));
```

Comment: Using `File` with `pw.MemoryImage` gives me the following error : **The argument type 'File' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'.**   .   I can do `final  myImage =  await rootBundle.load('path-to-the-image/image.png').then((value) => value.buffer.asUint8List());` , and it works, but it is incredibly slow.